# How to filter emails from Google Docs?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, gmail-filters

Emails from Google Docs are sent from the personal email address rather than from noreply address.

So when I receive a notification about that somebody has shared a document with me, I see somebody@gmail.com address in the "From" line. However, these emails usually don't have any useful meaning and I want to filter them to a particular label for GMail notifications to move it away from Inbox. Since there is no filter parameter like "sent via" how can I do that?

To make it clear, I am interested in filtering **incoming** emails.

Comment: I just sent myself an e-mail through a spreadsheet, but I couldn't find it in the sent items....

Comment: I'm writing about the mail from other people. It comes when they share something with me.

Comment: Are you talking about emailing collaborators, emailing the document as an attachment, or something else?

Comment: Emailing collaborators. It is notification from Google Drive that somebody has shared a document with me.

Comment: Try searching for the following string in your mail box: `IN:INBOX HAS DOCUMENTS`. You can adjust the search and then you can select them all and archive them somewhere.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Unfortunately, these emails don't have attachments, so I can't find them with the provided query.

Comment: Try: `from:(google drive)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All sent items from within Google Apps are signed like this:

> example@example.com (Google Drive)

If you search for those items in the search field like this:
[image]

you can either:

1. Select them manually, to do what ever you want;
2. Prior to searching, you can create a filter.

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm now using the following query:

```
from:(docs.google.com OR drive-shares-noreply@google.com)
```

It seems to catch all incoming emails regarding shared Google Drive documents and comments on them.

Answer (score 0):

In case you got here while looking for an option to search Gmail for Google Docs, try:

`to:me has:document` - All mails sent to you which includes a Google Document.

Here's more [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)